# ASP.NET Core DI consuming class which has IOption Pattern DI constructor

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

How can I call a class which has dependency injection `IOption` pattern in its constructor?

```
public class Myclass
{
    private readonly AppSettings _appSettings;

    public Myclass(IOptions<MYAppSettings> AppSettings)
    {
        _appSettings = AppSettings.Value;
    }
}

public class service
{
    public void send()
    {
        var x = Myclass();    // how can send IOptions parameter?
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Pass `MyClass` to `Service` constructor.

Comment: -or- pass `IOptions<MYAppSettings>` as parameter into `Service`'s constructor, store it in a private field, and pass it along to the `Myclass` constructor upon creation.

Comment: You just need to use Constructor injection in `Service` Class.